# Correct usage of "Ashkenaz"/"Ashkenazi"/"Ashkenazic"/"Ashkenazim"?

Tags: names, ashkenazi, language, english, communities

...Also, of course, Sefard/Sefardi/Sefardic/Sefardim.

I see these terms used interchangeably, and use them myself that way, but would rather use them correctly.

All are, at least marginally, pronouns. But within that, I seek a little more granularity: Which are (properly) nouns? Adjectives? Adverbs?

Please provide some sort of corroboration--not just explanation--for your answer.

Comment: Ashkenazim is the plural. Ashkenazic is the adjective. Ashkenaz and Ashkenazi are synonyms I would say. On the other side Sefard is something else, it refers to a Polish prayer nusach and IS NOT sefardi

Comment: @mbloch Good point on "Sfard" being just a nusach. "Ashkenaz" too, no?

Comment: More important Sfard doesn't below in the Sefard/Sefardi/Sefardic/Sefardim line - it is something else and nusach sfard is very different from nusach sefardi (or edot hamizrach as is said in Israel)

Comment: Is this on topic?

Comment: @mbloch "Sefard" is the name of a place and usually refers to Spain. IIRC, the name is mentioned in either Bresihit or parshat Noach, and I haveto remind myself what area in the world it referred to, then. Same idea would be for "Ashkenaz", whom I think is one of Cana'ans grandsons?

Comment: @DanF in modern Hebrew Spain is Sefarad

Comment: Curious ... wouldn't a group of Wikipedia articles provide some insights to answer this question?

Comment: @mbloch Modern Hebrew, yes. But see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sepharad for example. There is some dispute as to what it originally meant. Obviously, today, the term "Sefardi" refers to a large group of people, few of whom originated or ever lived in Spain. Which, leads the question as to why they are called "Sefardim".

Comment: @DoubleAA I think so; please see "Language used in Judaism" here: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/1474/1516

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this](http://www.jewfaq.org/ashkseph.htm) page:

> The adjective "Ashkenazic" and corresponding nouns, Ashkenazi
>   (singular) and Ashkenazim (plural) are derived from the Hebrew word
>   "Ashkenaz," which is used to refer to Germany.

...I searched the literature for confirmation and found there were two camps:

(1)

(Opinions which agree with the above):

Dovid Katz, *Yiddish and Power* ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=3QS4BgAAQBAJ&pg=PT30&dq=Ashkenaz%20Ashkenazic%20Ashkenazi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi33f3a7M7MAhVK2IMKHar6DbYQ6AEINDAE#v=onepage&q=Ashkenaz%20Ashkenazic%20Ashkenazi&f=false)): **Ashkenaz=name of an ancient civilization; Ashkenazim=people; Ashkenazi=a person; Ashkenazic=adjective**

*The New York Times Manual of Style and Usage* ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=AfbaCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA26&dq=The%20name%20is%20also%20used%20as%20an%20adjective,%20along%20with%20Ashkenazic,%20as%20in&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiS6Puy7s7MAhUK3IMKHSP8Ap8Q6AEIOTAG#v=onepage&q=The%20name%20is%20also%20used%20as%20an%20adjective%2C%20along%20with%20Ashkenazic%2C%20as%20in&f=false)): "*Ashkenazi* is the term for a Jew who settled in middle or northern Europe after the Diaspora, or that Jew's descendant. The plural is *Ashkenazim*, and the adjective is *Ashkenazic*."

(2)

(I consider these variant [identical] opinions):

Leo Rosten, *The New Joys of Yiddish*: Completely Updated says ([here](https://books.google.com/books?id=V04IRE3SwmgC&pg=PA18&dq=Ashkenaz%20Ashkenazic%20Ashkenazi&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiHy5ru7M7MAhXL8YMKHdorB7k4ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=Ashkenaz%20Ashkenazic%20Ashkenazi&f=false)): "'Ashkenazic' is an English adaptation of 'Ashkenazi' *[i.e., implying that both are adjectives --SAH]*. [...] [From] Hebrew: *Ashkenaz*, 'Germany.'" --...But, separately, he lists "Ashkenazi/Ashkenazim (plural)/Ashkenazic (adjective)" [sic] as the three variants, implying that "Ashkenazi" is a singular noun. (The definition under this heading begins: "Ashkenazim and Sephardim are the two main branches of Jewry," which seems to confirm this interpretation.)

--In short, Leo Rosten thinks "Ashkenazi" is an adjective and/or a singular noun for a person; "Ashkenazim" is a plural noun for people; "Ashkenaz" is a place; and "Ashkenazic" is another adjective.

Sol Steinmetz, *Dictionary of Jewish Usage: A Guide to the Use of Jewish Terms*, p. 11, thinks the same: "The name ['Ashkenazi'] is also used as an adjective, along with Ashkenazic, as in Ashkenazi (or Ashkenazic) Jews, the Ashkenazi (or Ashkenazic) Hebrew pronunciation."